# Text sanitization is AngularJS 1.8.3

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a sample text string (shown below) that contains html tags  :

`SAMPLE_TEXT= "<b>This is bold Text</b>"`

This text is rendered on the UI using `ng-bind-html`

`<span ng-bind-html="::'SAMPLE_TEXT' | translate" </span>`

If I render this text using AngularJS 1.8.0. The text is rendered as bold formatted text.
However, AngularJS 1.8.3 renders the  tags as it is. (No bold text conversion)

Seems like some text sanitization is happening (I'm not exactly sure). How do I achieve the results similar to 1.8.0